Puppet show from the late 80's, animals in a forest, lemmings?
This was a puppet show that was on in the UK in the late 80's. It involved a group of animals that lived together in a forest. It may have been on channel four on a Sunday afternoon. It could have been a feature length episode or maybe just a one off, if it was a series it was short lived. 
The only scene I actually remember was that there was a character called Lemmy the Lemming who lived apart from the other animals with his bad biker gang types and there was a musical interlude where he sang a song called 'Black Mass in my Caravan' in a caravan, dressed in rock leathers in a heavy metal style. 
None of my school friends saw it and I cannot find any clips on youtube as I don't remember the name of the show.

Possibly "fraggle rock"? http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0085017/

Based on a search for "Lemmy the Lemming" I also came up with "Gohpers (1990)" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gophers!

Deffo not fraggle rock but Gophers is ringing a bell.

Yeah. I barely remember Gophers (mainly the intro, and I don't remember the lemming there at all), but the rest fits and there are plenty of clips from the show on Youtube.

I think that is it, I thought it was puppets but its men with animal heads on. Thanks,

Based on a Google search for "Lemmy the Lemming" I came up with Gophers! (1990) 
From Wikipedia

Gophers! was a Channel 4 children's programme about a family of
  American gophers who move into a new neighbourhood, called Sycamore
  Heights, living next door to a family of uptight but well-intentioned
  rabbits, The Burrows. There were many recurring jokes within this
  short lived show such as Arthur Burrows' vegetables planning a
  rebellion to escape his garden, a mad scientist ferret called Dr
  Wince, whose ambition was to conquer the world by obtaining a crystal
  buried in the Gophers' garden with the help of his reptilian servant
  Sly, and an alien in love with a zucchini determined to get home. Also
  there were Stereotypical "Mexican" cockroaches (Dressed in costumes of
  Mexican Peasant Revolutionaries of the Mexican Revolution of 1910) who
  lived in the Gophers' house or Trailer Park Mobile Home always trying
  to steal their food.

